複数の要素をモバイルまたはPCでの画面に応じて、縦並びまたは横並びになるようにしたい
３つの要素をモバイル用画面では縦並び、PC用画面では横並びにしたいです。現在モバイル用画面で縦並びにはできていますが、PC用画面で横並びにできていません。HTML、CSSは以下のようです。


@import url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/BIZ+UDGothic');
h1{
    font-size: 24px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 20px;
}
h3{
    font-size: 16px;
}
h4{
    font-size: 13px;
}
h5{
    font-size: 12px;
}
body{
    z-index: -5;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'BIZUDPGothic';
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}

/* ハンバーガーメニューのスタイル */
.menu {
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  strong{
    position: fixed;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 55px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 12px;
    z-index: 1001;
    font: normal normal bold 12px/1px BIZ UDPGothic;
  }
  .square-menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 8px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 67px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
    background: #FFD610;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    top: 30px;
    right:10px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  
  .hamburger:before,
  .hamburger:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .hamburger:before {
    top: -10px;
  }
  
  .hamburger:after {
    bottom: -10px;
  }
  
  /* メニューの開閉時のスタイル */
  #menu-toggle:checked + .menu .hamburger {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  /* メニューのコンテンツ */
  .menu-content {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 998;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFD610;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .menu-content {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .menu-content nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .menu-content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  .menu-content ul li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .menu-content ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  /* チェックボックスを隠す */
  .hidden {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }



header h1{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
}
header img{
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 97px;
    height: 66px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.about-img img{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 314px;
    height: 619px;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.square{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 0px;
    
    right: 0px;
    width: 283px;
    height: 667px;
    background: #242424 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
}
#about{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#about h1{
    font: normal normal bold 56px/53px BIZ UDPGothic;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
#about p{
    font: normal normal bold 16px/9px BIZ UDPGothic;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.s1{
    text-align: center;
}
#service{
    
    width: 100%;
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
.service-start{
    position: relative;
}
.box1{
    position: absolute;
    top: -104px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 291px;
    height: 253px;
    background-color: rgba(229, 248, 254, 1); 
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 48px );
}
.service-start h2{
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
    font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #707070;
}
.service-start .s1{
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
}

.service-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
}
.service-container .in{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.service-img1{
    display: block;
}
.service-img1 img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.service-text .ttl{
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    left: -8px;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/24px BIZ UDPGothic;
}
.service-text .ttl span{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffd610;
    padding: 10px 28.5px 10px 28.5px;
}
.in .service-number{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #FFD610;
    top: -30px;
    right: 5px;
    font: italic normal normal 60px/73px Verdana;

}
.service-text{
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    padding: 40px 20px 15px 20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.service-text .cach{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/24px BIZ UDPGothic;
}
.txt{
    font: normal normal normal 16px/19px BIZ UDPGothic;
}

#INFORMATION{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px;
    margin-top: 116px;
    margin-bottom: 176px;
}
.background{
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 370px;
    left: 2.5%;
    z-index:-1;
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 226, 88, 1); 
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, 
    transparent 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 48px );
    
}   
.announce{
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 313px;
    height: 278px;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}
.announce-box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#INFORMATION .mokuji{
    font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
    margin-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #707070;
}
#INFORMATION  a{
    color: #000000;
    font: normal normal normal 16px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
} 
#INFORMATION  h4{
    font: normal normal normal 12px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}  
#INFORMATION  ul {
    list-style: none; /* リストアイテムのマーカーを消す */
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
.bottun-yellow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    padding-left: 58px;
    padding-right: 57px;
    padding-top: 10;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    
    background: #FFD610 ;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;  
}
.Information-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#RECRUIT{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.recruit-start{
    position: relative;
}
.box2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    top: -104px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 291px;
    height: 253px;
    background-color: rgba(229, 248, 254, 1); 
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 48px );
}
.box3{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 100px;
    left: 66px;
    width: 295px;
    height: 252px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 226, 88, 1);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 48px );
}
.recruit-start h2{
    font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -125px;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #707070;
}
.recruit-img img{
    position: relative;
    width: 375px;
    height: 250px;
    top: -90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.recruit-txt{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 310px;
    height: 211px;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    left: 40px;
    background: #FFFFFFB0;
    font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
}
.black-bottum{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 38px;
    padding-right: 37px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    
    background:#242424 ;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 26px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#irai{
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 84px;
    
}
.back-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px; 
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -250px;
}
.irai-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
.irai-text{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px ;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    font: normal normal normal 24px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
    
}
.bottun-yellow-2{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    
    background: #FFD610 ;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
    
    width: 210px;
    
    
}
.logo img{
    width: 97.08px;
    height: 65.71px;
    
}
#CONTACT{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 115px;

}
#CONTACT h5{
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 12px/16px BIZ UDPGothic;
}
.black-bottum2{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 38px;
    padding-right: 37px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    
    background:#242424 ;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 21px;
    
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/32px BIZ UDPGothic;
    
    display: inline-block;
    
}
footer{
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 226, 88, 1); 
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px,rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 24px,rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 48px );
    margin: 0;
    
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
footer h3{
    
    font: normal normal normal 16px/16px BIZ UDPGothic;
    margin-top: 33px;
    

}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    header{
        width: 1920px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 8px;
        left: 6px;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    #about{
        height: 1080px;
    }
    .about-img img{
        width: 70%;
        height: 980px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -100;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .square{
        width: 80%;
        height: 1080px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
        top: 0px;
        
        right: 0px;
        background: #242424 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #about h1{
    text-align: right;
    font: normal normal bold 74px/90px BIZ UDPGothic;
    letter-spacing: 4.66px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #about p{
        text-align: right;
        font: normal normal bold 32px/9px BIZ UDPGothic;
        letter-spacing: 2.02px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-top: 35px;
    }
    .about-text{
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        right: 278px;
    }
    #irai{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 590.77px;
        margin-bottom: 188px;
        
    }
    .back-image img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 590.77px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        top: -250px;
    }
    .irai-text{
        font: normal normal normal 42px/64px BIZ UDPGothic;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    }


    #RECRUIT{
        padding-top: 191px;
        height: 1130px;
    }
    .recruit-start{
        position: relative;
    }
    .box2{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
        top: -210px;
        left: 401px;
        width: 527px;
        height: 459px;
        background-color: rgba(229, 248, 254, 1); 
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 24px, rgba(215, 244, 252, 1) 48px );
    }
    .box3{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
        top: 0px;
        left: 708px;
        width: 812px;
        height: 421px;

        background-color: rgba(255, 226, 88, 1);
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 24px, rgba(254, 215, 13, 1) 48px );
    }
    .recruit-start h2{
        font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
        position: relative;
        left: 20px;
        top: -125px;
    }
    .recruit-img img{
        position: relative;
        width: 812px;
        height: 552px;
        top: -200px;
        left: 676px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .recruit-txt{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 901px;
        height: 414px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3326px;
        left: 416px;
        background: #FFFFFFB0;
        font: normal normal bold 40px/48px BIZ UDPGothic;
    }
    .recruit-start h2{
        font: normal normal bold 24px/29px BIZ UDPGothic;
        position: relative;
        left: 417px;
        top: -125px;
        display: inline;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #707070;
    }
    
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>第10回、第11回 課題</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1><img src="ait-wd-logo_white_delpad.svg"></h1>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" class="hidden">
            <label for="menu-toggle" class="menu">
                <span class="hamburger"></span>
                <strong>MENU</strong>
                <div class="square-menu"></div>
            </label>
            <div class="menu-content">
                <nav class="m">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <p>私たちの会社について</p>
                        <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                        <p>お仕事の詳細</p>
                        <li><a href="#INFORMATION">Information</a></li>
                        <p>お知らせ一覧</p>
                         <li><a href="#RECRUIT">Recruit</a></li>
                        <p>採用情報</p>
                        <li><a href="#CONTACT">Contact</a></li>
                        <p>お問い合わせ</p>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    
        

    <section id="about">
        <div class="about-text">
            <h1>わくわくする<br>モノづくりで<br>未来を創る</h1>
            <p>職人による職人のための会社</p>
        </div>
        <div class="about-img">
            <img src="OZP_senbanwoganbaru1188_TP_V.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="service">
        <div class="service-start">
            <span class="box1"></span>
            <h2>SERVICE</h2>
            <p class="s1">モノづくりの楽しさを追求する
                <br>町の組み立てやさん</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service-container">
            <div class="in">
                <span class="service-img1">
                    <img src="YOTAKA160328440I9A9327_TP_V4.jpg">
                </span>
              <p class="service-number">01</p>
                <div class="service-text">
                    <h3 class="ttl"><span>創業50年の経験と実績</span></h3>
                    <p class="cach">おかげさまで半世紀</p>
                    <p class="txt">町工場から始まり、今に至るまで、日本を代表する
                    組み立てメーカーとして、長年の経験と実績で
                    モノづくりを支えています。</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="in">
                <span class="service-img1">
                    <img src="tsuchimoto0I9A6635_TP_V4.jpg">
                </span>
                <p class="service-number">02</p>
                <div class="service-text">
                    <h3 class="ttl"><span>安全管理はお任せください</span></h3>
                    <p class="cach">モノづくりに安全点検は不可欠</p>
                    <p class="txt">「安心」・「安全」のノウハウは、他社に引けを取り
                        ません。制作物の強度・整合性・材質、全てに
                        こだわり、万全のチェックを行っております。</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="in">
                <span class="service-img1">
                    <img src="PASONA_21_TP_V4.jpg">
                </span>
                <p class="service-number">03</p>
                <div class="service-text">
                    <h3 class="ttl"><span>企画・提案もお任せ</span></h3>
                    <p class="cach">新規事業も大歓迎</p>
                    <p class="txt">当社では、企画から設計・制作・塗装・修理・メン
                        テナンスまで、一貫して行います。面白いモノづ
                        くりの提案も柔軟にさせていただきます。</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="INFORMATION">
        <h1 class="mokuji">INFORMATION</h1>
        <div class="background">
        <div class="announce-box">
            <div class="announce">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h4>2022.01.01 メディア</h4>
                    <a href="#">〇〇新聞に掲載されました</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4>2022.01.01 お知らせ</h4>
                    <a href="#">新しいサービス提供開始のお知らせ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4>2022.01.01</h4>
                    <a href="#">サイトリニューアル</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Information-container">
            <a class="bottun-yellow" href="#">一覧を見る</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="RECRUIT">
        <div class="recruit-start">
            <h2>RECRUIT</h2>
            <span class="box2"></span>
            <span class="box3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="recruit-container">
            <span class="recruit-img">
                <img src="PASONA_19_TP_V4.jpg">
            </span>
            <div class="recruit-txt">
                <h1 p>一緒にわくわくしたい<br>仲間を募集しています</h1>
                <a class="black-bottum" href="#">採用情報を見る</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="irai">
        <div class="iti">
            <div class="irai-container">
                <p class="irai-text">
                    ”こんなことできますか？”<br>お仕事のご依頼・ご相談は<br>こちらからもどうぞ
                </p>
                <a class="bottun-yellow-2" href="#">ご依頼・ご相談</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back-image">
            <img src="PAK85_kikaihandle20141028182041_TP_V4.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="CONTACT">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="ait-wd-logo_black_delpad (1).svg">
        </div>
        <h5>
            〒000-0000<br>
            〇〇県〇〇市１丁目234番地<br>tel:0000-00-0000<br>fax:0000-00-0000
        </h5>
        <a class="black-bottum2" href="#">お問い合わせ</a>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <h3>©️ 2022 AIT-WD.</h3>
    </footer>
</body>



